# Seeking National Land Cover Vector Dataset?

Tags: data, land-cover, vector-layer

I am looking for a National land cover vector dataset.

I tried to work with the National Land Cover Database 2011, downloaded the dataset but it was a picture file.

Comment: You didn't specify which nation you are interested in.  In case it's Australia, you can take a look at:  http://www.ga.gov.au/scientific-topics/earth-obs/accessing-satellite-imagery/landcover (edit:  oops, that's a raster, not a vector).  You should probably update your question to be a bit more specific.

Comment: If it's open data the place to ask may be the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.